# select one of outcomes randomally in sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am trying to randomly choose one of two outcomes in **sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
if [$[ $RANDOM % 2] -eq 1 ]
then
echo yes
else
echo no
fi
```

gives

```
sh-3.2$ sh test.sh
test.bash: line 4: [1: command not found
no
```

Obviously, it's trying to execute the (0,1) as a command. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just put a space after the first [, like

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $[ $RANDOM % 2] -eq 1 ]
then
echo yes
else
echo no
fi
```

Comment: Uh.. that, ``$[ $RANDOM % 2]`` seems a bit unorthodox, but still.. why not.. will do it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here mate, you just missed [the syntax](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) a bit :

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ $((RANDOM % 2)) -eq 1 ]] ; then
    echo "yes"
else
    echo "no"
fi
```

now, if you want to impress yer friends, you could try [just this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/list-cons.html#LISTCONSREF):

```
[[ $((RANDOM % 2)) -eq 1 ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

By the way, best practices and guides, I strongly recommend this web book: [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [*bash*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), you can use `((expression))` format:

```
#! /bin/sh
if ((RANDOM%2==1)); then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

Comment: I was aware of that, but I wanted this to be portable.